# Use a command block to "Sense" a player in a certain area

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

On my friends and my server, we have a skyblock map. My issue is when somebody joins they spawn above the Void. What I need is for a command block to determine if a player is near the Void and send a redstone signal to another command block that will teleport them to the main island.

Comment: I have the teleporting part done

Comment: [/testfor](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Testfor#Command-Block-only_commands)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a [redstone clock (I recommend the repeater ones)](http://www.minecraftguides.org/clocks/) and attach it to a command block with this command:

```
/spawnpoint @a X Y Z
```

Remember to turn off command block output to prevent spam!

```
/gamerule doCommandBlockOutput false
```

Hope it helped. :)

Comment: That's a pretty clever solution, I wish I'd known that.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is if they "spawn" above void then go to the spot you want to be the spawn point and type in the chat bar /setworldspawn

This will set the worlds spawn to that spot instead of trying to have lots of command blocks

:)

Comment: I did that and they still spawn above the void, however it gives a chance of spawning on the island

Answer (score 1):

Why not just get the [Essentials plugin](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/essentials/) and set the spawn somewhere else? You can use the /setspawn command. This is, of course, assuming you're using Bukkit.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can just use `/setworldspawn` and that will make everyone spawn in the same general area.